# How can I add a tabbed menu to a carousel view in Xamarin forms?

Tags: ios, mobile, xamarin, navigation, xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement an interface where there are five pages that can be swiped and dragged between but you can also change the page by tapping on a tabbed bar at the bottom.

I am writing a custom renderer for the CarouselPage but I can not add a tabbed bar at the bottom because the iOS UITabBar requires and array of UIViewControllers to switch between and I only have access to the pages.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (ExtendedCarouselPage), typeof (ExtendedCarouselPageRenderer))]

namespace CustomRenderer.iOS
{
    public class ExtendedCarouselPageRenderer : CarouselPageRenderer
    {
        protected UITabBar tabBar;

        protected override void OnElementChanged (VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
                base.OnElementChanged (e);

                tabBar = new UITabBar (new CGRect (0, this.View.Frame.Height * 0.9, this.View.Frame.Width, this.View.Frame.Height * 0.1));
                tabBar.Items = new UITabBarItem[]{
                        new UITabBarItem("Hello",UIImage.FromFile("Homeicon.png"),UIImage.FromFile("HomeiconBlue.png")),
                        new UITabBarItem("World", UIImage.FromFile("Homeicon.png"),UIImage.FromFile("HomeiconBlue.png"))
                };

                tabBar.Bounds = new CGRect (0, this.View.Frame.Height * 0.9, this.View.Frame.Width, this.View.Frame.Height * 0.1);
                tabBar.Frame = new CGRect (0, this.View.Frame.Height * 0.9, this.View.Frame.Width, this.View.Frame.Height * 0.1);

                this.NativeView.AddSubview(tabBar);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't find a lot of guides on writing more complex custom renderers. There are plenty for just Xamarin IOS but a lot of the code does not apply to a custom renderer.